# How to understand this schedule of a special issue?

Tags: publications, journals, journal-workflow, special-issue

I need to publish a paper before the end of this year and found an announcement with these details:

> Submission deadline: 14 July 2022
> Final manuscript due: 1 November 2022
> Tentative publication date: 20 January 2023

Does that mean that the accepted paper should be in November or after that? I sent an email to the lead editor but without a response.

I got that it is supposed that all final versions send before the first of  November, but when will authors be notified of acceptance?

Comment: The schedule seems clear, but I can't understand the sentence "the accepted paper should be in November month" in your question. Please rewrite it with different words. I voted to close as "needs detail" for now, but I am happy to vote to reopen it when your question is clear.

Answer (score 17):

You missed the submission deadline of the 14th of July and are out of luck. On that date, you needed to have sent your manuscript to the journal for review. If the paper would have been accepted, you would have until November 1st to submit the final version. By January 20, the journal would have done the final editing / compilation work and published the issue with your paper.

If the journal special issue has too few submissions, it is possible that they extend the submission deadline. You should check whether this has happened.

Answer (score 6):

14 July: you must submit your manuscript by this date.

1 November: By this date a final decision will have been made for all manuscripts. By implication, you will have received a decision before this date, and if the decision was revise, you need to submit your revision before this date.

20 January: all articles published online, assigned DOIs, etc.

Comment: thanks but excuse me, when the accepted paper will be notified ?

Comment: Sometime before 1 November.